# OpenGL not supported by video driver

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, libgdx, opengl-3

I installed libGDX and wrote a simple code to display a window. But when I run it, I get an exception that says : OpenGL is not supported by video driver. Then I installed GLEW (OPENGL EXTENSION WRANGLER LIBRARY). Then I went to the installation folder, unzipped the contents to a new folder, went to the new folder, clicked on bin, release, win32, and finally glewinfo. It opened a notepad file that showed me that name of my video card and said that it supported OpenGL 2.1. But in eclipse (mars) and libgdx (gdx-setup tool) i cant get my program to run even if i set config.useGL30 = false. Pleaee help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between OpenGL ES and OpenGL.

- OpenGL is the desktop version.
- OpenGL ES is the mobile version.

libGDX uses OpenGL ES since it runs on mobile and desktop.

- To run OpenGL ES 2.0 you need OpenGL 4.1 on a desktop.
- To run OpenGL ES 3.0 you need OpenGL 4.3 on a desktop.

---

EDIT according to derhass

Note that this are only the specifications and actual implementations can provide full support for OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0 prior to these versions.

But this seems not to be the case for your setup.

Comment: Oh!! Okay! Thanks for replying. I didn't know about it as I was new to libGDX programming. Thanks again! :)

Comment: One more thing.. You said that to run opengl es 2.0 i need to install open gl 4.1.. So do I have to download that software? If so can you please leave a link. I would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: @Pinkie Swirl: That is not neccesarrily the case. It is true that desktop GL 4.1 defines backwards compatibility to GLES2, and 4.3 to GLES3. However, desktop GL implementations are free to support GLES contexts directly (no matter if they have  support for desktop GL 4.x or not), and many actually do.

Comment: @AadiShah this software is installed with your drivers, so your video card might not support a higher version.

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay.. But if I update my video drivers, will they support open gl?

Comment: I don't know, if it is that old, most likely not. http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php is a tool to view what version and extensions your system supports.